# Will this voltage divider keep my MOSFET on?

Tags: mosfet, voltage-divider

I'm hoping to use a voltage divider to supply voltage to the gates of some MOSFETs. The divider will be scaled at a voltage ratio of 1:10 to a high voltage battery that will discharge from 240 V to about 80 V, so the voltage in the divider should range from 24 V to 8 V. Some cheap low voltage cutoffs will either send voltage to the gates or not, depending on the battery voltage.

The goal here is to intentionally discharge this battery while using the FETs to control discharge rate by removing parallel resistors from the discharge, thus increasing discharge resistance.

I want the MOSFETs to behave as switches, fully on or fully off. They have a gate drive of 10 V and a V<sub>GSS</sub> of +/-30 V.

**Question 1:** Am I generally correct that a high/low of 24 V and 8 V will work to keep the FET fully on? 24 V isn't too close to "approaching absolute max voltage" is it? 8 V is less than 10 V, but based on the charts in the datasheets it seems like there's little to no difference.

Now, my concern is that the "gate input resistance" is listed as 6 ohms. I've been playing with the [Digi-Key voltage divider with load calculator](https://www.digikey.com/en/resources/conversion-calculators/conversion-calculator-voltage-divider) and I think I'm just confusing myself. If the low voltage cutoffs have a voltmeter with about 70,000 ohms, I can put that in as the load, which leaves a nice 24 V for the output of the divider. When I put the load as 6 ohms I start to get a little confused as to what I'm looking at.

**Question 2:** At the start of discharge can I count on ~24 V being the voltage received at the gate of the MOSFET? If so, do I need to worry about the current being too low to get the FETs on quickly, thus inviting unwanted dissipation?

**Question 3:** My understanding is that the resistance on the gate is very low until the MOSFET is completely on, and at that point the gate resistance becomes almost infinite, so current at the gate of the MOSFET is really only an issue when turning it on, after which it's voltage driven and the current across the gate is nearly zero. Is this understanding correct?

If necessary or if advisable I have a USB-controlled relay module that I could use to supply an amp or two at 12 V to the gates to get them to open quickly when I initially start discharge of the battery.

**Question 4:** If I did that would it be the case that once I got the gates open that the gate resistance would shoot up and would allow me to then rely on the voltage divider to keep them open without keeping the relay-fed voltage applied?

**Question 5:** What happens, if instead of having one low voltage cutoff supplying one MOSFET gate, I have several low voltage cutoffs supplying several MOSFET gates, all in parallel on this same voltage divider.

Here's a basic schematic what what I'm hoping to do. Let's ignore that I'm pretty sure the FET is backwards in this schematic, as in real life I'll connect source to ground like I'm supposed to, and let's not worry about what the "Stuff" resistor is. Also - R1 will actually be four 450 Ω 100 W resistors (to safely spread out heat dissipation). The 70,000 ohm resistor is meant to represent the meter in my low voltage cutoff. And here's a link to the [datasheet](https://www.littelfuse.com/%7E/media/electronics/datasheets/discrete_mosfets/littelfuse_discrete_mosfets_n-channel_ultra_junction_ixtp8n65x2m_datasheet.pdf.pdf) of the FET I'm looking at.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5meoN.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

To spell out what I'm trying to do a bit more clearly:

I'm intentionally discharging a battery to a specific voltage, and I want slow the rate of discharge as the battery voltage decreases. I've been doing this manually by placing a bunch of resistors (light bulbs) in parallel and then removing bulbs from the chain as the battery voltage decreases, so as to the increase the discharge resistance.

I want to automate this, and to do so I want to use these cheap little low voltage cutoffs I have that work in the 0-60 V range. I can't use those directly as switches because my battery is at too high voltage. So I want to use a voltage divider in front of the cutoffs and use the cutoffs to either supply power to the MOSFETs or not, letting the MOSFETs do the switching.

Given this, using a voltage divider which requires a ton of dissipation is not really counter to my goal. I'll also note that the FETs/ resistors aren't going to be mounted to a PCB board, this is all going down inside a milk crate essentially.

I just need to be sure that the MOSFETs will stay on until the low voltage cutoffs stop feeding the gates.

Comment: The resistance values might need some redesigning. 240V over 2k ohms means current of 120mA and thus total of 28.8 watts of dissipation in total.

Comment: Isn't 24 V a bit over the top for absolute ratings? (I mean Vgs.)

Comment: Yeah, that's why I'm planning to use 4 100w/ 450 ohm resistors to act as the 1800 ohm resistor. I'll heatsink and fan those resistors as well.

Comment: As for 24v being over the top. Is it? Since the battery is discharging from 240v to 80v or so I need to use a divider ratio where the whole spectrum falls within the working range of the fet, if possible.

Comment: Just peaked at the datasheet. Seems to say 20 V in the absolute max ratings. But perhaps I'm misreading something. I'm not perfect.... yet, anyway. ;)

Comment: You are not quite on the right track here. I think you are adjacent to the track, and understand a little about what goes on at the track. To torture a metaphor. A simple solution will be to use a 1/3 voltage divider and feed the voltage from that to a high input voltage linear regulator. Run the NMOS gates from the linear regulator. Dissipating 30 watts in a voltage divider for a MOSFET gate is not a reasonable arrangement. Even if you ignore my regulator suggestion and use a divider, size it for like 100 uA, not 120 mA.

Comment: For your purposes, completely ignore the 6 ohm gate resistance. Also, you should put a Zener diode from source to gate to protect the gate. Like a 12 V zener diode.

Comment: I'm seeing +/- 30v for Vgss Continous and +/- 40v for Vgss Transient. I also may misunderstand what these mean, though, as I too am imperfect.

Comment: @mkeith 1/3 won't work for my cut/offs but 1/4 would. As for dissipating 30 watts- I understand that it may seem a bit silly, but if the point of the whole arrangment is to intentionally discharge a battery, I have to dissipate those watts somewhere. Given that, is it STILL unreasonable?  The "Stuff" resistor is just going to be more resistors (or light bulbs) meant to intentionally discharge this battery. Obviously if I were trying to minimize battery discharge I would 100% agree that this voltage divider would be dumb.

Comment: Your schematic wrongly shows a different common Mosfet part number than the weird Mosfet in your text. The resistor values in your schematic are Way TOO LOW. The unknown value of the R4 load resistor determines how much minimum gate voltage is needed.

Comment: Did not realize that the schematic was showing a part number! Assume that the fet in question is the fet I linked to.

Comment: I didn't realize you were building a battery discharger. Even so, I would not want to dissipate so much power just to drive the gate. Anyway, see my answer.

Answer (score 4):

I feel I should first address something you already know, which is that your circuit will kill you if you so much as look at it the wrong way. You will have to take several precautions, such as keeping distances between nodes of high potential difference sufficiently separated and insulated. Nothing I say here address these problems, so this answer is incomplete.

Disclaimer done, some things about your question and MOSFETs which are important:

1. I don't know where you get that "gate resistance" figure of 6Ω from, it's misleading. The resistance between gate and either drain or source is extremely high, probably in the Gigohms or higher, depending on the device. For low frequency applications like this, gate impedance is of little or no concern. Did you mean "channel" resistance, the resistance from drain to source? That could well be 6Ω, so I'll assume that from now on.
2. The MOSFET will not simply be "off" or "on" because the rate of change of voltage at the gate will be small. I assume that this battery will discharge over many minutes or hours, and there will necessarily be a period during which the potential appearing at the MOSFET's gate will be *traversing* a region between those two states, and the channel will have a non-zero, finite resistance. That's when the transistor is dissipating power, and getting hot.
3. You didn't tell us what currents you expect to see anywhere. Ambiguity in the question means ambiguity in the answer. I had to make a lot of assumptions. It's important because it will determine how much power is dissipated in the components in that path of current, and how hot they get.
4. You have R2 and R3 in parallel, for a combined *single* resistance of slightly less than 200Ω. Any calculations involving that now-non-existent 70kΩ resistance are necessarily wrong.
5. The best design will be the one that kills you least. If the negative end of the battery is closest to earth potential, then you should use N-channel MOSFETs, and keep as many circuit potentials as close to zero volts as possible. If the +240V end is closest to earth potential, then it's P-channel devices, and potentials should mostly be close to the positive battery side. I'm going with the former, using N-channel transistors.

Here's a circuit to illustrate the region during discharge where the MOSFET is half-conducting, and dissipating power:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEm7Rt.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Graphs of battery voltage and drain potential, and power dissipated in the MOSFET:

[image]

[image]

As you can see, there's a period of a couple of hours where the voltage across M1 is *between* 0 and the battery voltage, and that's where it's operating in the linear region, between on and off, dissipating power. Discharge current at the peak of power dissipation (50W) in M1 is about 0.5A. Clearly, if you want discharge currents greater than this, power dissipation over that period will be correspondingly higher. The MOSFET will require serious heat-sinking, and forced-air cooling, if it is to survive.

You cannot solve this problem using resistances alone. Any network of resistors you use is a linear system, and the graph of gate voltage vs. time (as the battery discharges) will be a straight line, and will necessarily take time to traverse this active region of the MOSFET behaviour. There's no hope of clean on-or-off behaviour with this approach.

To address your questions about what gate voltages need to be applied in order to switch the MOSFET on, we need to look at the graph of gate potential, and identifiy the extremes, the points when the MOSFET is either completely off or completely on:

[image]

Here, the gate's threshold levels seem to be about 6.0V and 5.5V, but these will depend on the model of MOSFET you use. These values also depend on drain current, so we'll never be able to rely on them to any great degree. We may however use these ballpark figures to design a resistor divider that will provide gate voltages to switch on disharge paths as the battery voltage diminishes.

Knowing that the transistor we are using begins to switch off when gate potential drops below 5.5V, we can state that when the voltage drops to 80V we need the gates of all the transistors to be less than 5.5V, so that they are all off, and discharging ceases. That's a factor of:

$$
\begin{aligned}
F_{80} &= {V_{GATE\_80} \over V_{BAT\_MIN}} \\ \\
&= {5.5V \over 80V} \\ \\
&= 6.9\%
\end{aligned}
$$

You also need to define what battery potential will begin to switch off the first transistor in the group. That is, assuming all transistors are on when the battery voltage is 240V, what will be the battery voltage necessary to begin switching off the first one. Let's say 200V, at which point the gate shall be at 6.0V:

$$
\begin{aligned}
&= {6.0V \over 200V} \\ \\
&= 3.0\%
\end{aligned}
$$

I'll assume we need one more transistor (for a total of three), switching on/off somewhere between these extremes, where battery voltage is about 140V. Here we want a gate potential somewhere near the mid-point of the transistor's active range, about \$V_{GATE\_140} = 5.8V \$:

$$
\begin{aligned}
&= {5.8V \over 140V} \\ \\
&= 4.1\%
\end{aligned}
$$

Now we're ready to build a resistor divider to obtain these potentials from the battery:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4zMZK.png)</sup>

I've rounded the numbers, to keep them all simple. With this arrangement we obtain potentials \$V_{G1}\$, \$V_{G2}\$ and \$V_{G3}\$ which vary with \$V_{BAT}\$ in this way:

[image]

Obviously you choose whatever resistors you need to create whatever switching thresholds you want. The most important thing to note here is that the voltage across R1 can be close to 240V. Choose a resistor value here that won't dissipate more power than it can handle. In this case:

$$ P_{R1} \approx {{V_{R1}}^2 \over R_1} = {(240V)^2 \over 930k\Omega} = 62mW $$

The ratios here are what's important, not the absolute values. You could divide all resistor values by ten and obtain the same voltages, but R1 would then dissipate:

$$ P \approx = {(240V)^2 \over 93k\Omega} = 620mW $$

Obviously a resistor able to handle 620mW would then be required; something like a 1W device would be fine. Since MOSFET gate impedance is so high, you could probably get away with resistances as high as I've used here. The gates will not draw enough current to disturb the potentials at their junctions.

The complete circuit might look like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVG17h.png)</sup>

The first MOSFET to switch off will be the one with the lowest gate potential to start with. That's M3 here, then M2, and finally M1.

The most current that flows is when all three MOSFETs are on, which will be when battery voltage exceeds 200V. At 240V, that potential exists across each of R5, R6 and R7, and the total current flowing will be the sum of currents in each path. By Ohm's law, and Kirchhoff's current law:

$$
\begin{aligned}
I_{240} &= \frac{240V}{240\Omega} + \frac{240V}{240\Omega} + \frac{240V}{240\Omega} \\ \\
&= 3A
\end{aligned}
$$

That current will reduce when M3 switches off, at a battery voltage of about 200V. Then current is restricted to only two paths:

$$
\begin{aligned}
I_{200} &= \frac{200V}{240\Omega} + \frac{200V}{240\Omega} \\ \\
&= 1.7A
\end{aligned}
$$

I'll leave you to figure out the other threshold currents, but it's clear that when all three are off, the only current flowing will be the relatively miniscule current through the resistor divider chain.

Here's the plot of how current would diminish over time, as battery voltage drops:

[image]

It's worth noting that you could achieve a similar behaviour with a single resistor across the battery, with the caveat that current would flow all the way down to zero volts, instead of cutting off completely at 80V. Are you sure that's not a better solution?

Let's take a look at the power being dissipated in the MOSFETs during discharge:

[image]

The only way to solve this problem, and get the MOSFETs switching quickly between on and off states, is by using some non-linear signal conditioning. The easiest way I can think of (others may have better solutions) is using comparators.

A comparator permits us to generate a digital high or low signal (ideal for our MOSFETs' gates) resulting from a comparison of two potentials. When input potential A is greater than input B, output a low state. If B is greater than A, output high.

For this to work, you need a comparator for each MOSFET. I suggest the [LM339](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2901.pdf), containing four such units in a single package. To power this device you will need a low voltage supply. I  would suggest 12V, since this will result in comparator outputs of +12V and 0V, ideal for the MOSFET gates.

There are at least a dozen ways to get 12V from your 240V source, and I'll let you research them. You might even choose to power the whole thing from an independent 12V supply, but I'll stick here with the simplest way I can think of, using your battery's 240V. That would be a zener regulator, consisting of a single zener diode and resistor (I'll use three resistors here to distribute voltage and power among them, and keep stresses manageable):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIF4dx.png)</sup>

The voltage between ground and S is 12V, which is our comparator's power supply. The maximum current we can draw from S is about 7mA, at which point the diode is starved and stops regulating, but that should be enough to power our circuit. The resistor values are chosen such that the regulator can provide 7mA even when the battery voltage is down to 80V, and their power rating is is chosen to tolerate the heating caused when battery voltage is at its maximum of 240V.

A single comparator module shall be configured to compare some fixed fraction of the battery voltage (input B) with some reference potential we choose ourselves (input A). There shall also be some positive feedback to provide hysteresis, avoiding any instability (such as oscillation) that might occur when the inputs have very similar potentials.

The reference input voltage for each module will be derived from our steady 12V supply, using a resistor divider. It will be stabilised with a small capacitance, to prevent any noise sources from messing with our voltage.

The input potentials to the comparator need to fall within the comparator's own supply voltages, zero to +12V, and so we must scale down battery voltage (using a resistor divider) to become well within this range.

Putting all this together, a module would look like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fB2Hpt.png)</sup>

R12 and R13 are chosen to produce the same potential at A that you would see at B if the battery was at 200V. This means the comparator will switch output states when the battery voltage passes through 200V. Consequently the MOSFET, given a digital 0V or +12V signal from the comparator, will be switched emphatically between on and off states. Additional modules would use different values for R12 and R13, since they will trigger at different switching thresholds.

R15 provides positive feedback. My measurements here show about 30mV of hysteresis. Sadly, to implement positive feedback here requires that the voltage at B (the battery sense voltage) be modulated a little (by ±15mV or so in this case), but that shouldn't be a problem as long as switching thresholds of the modules are significantly further than 30mV from each other.

You need to implement the entire region in blue for each MOSFET. However the circuit in the pink box can be shared by all modules, node B being common to them all. That's because they all need to know what the battery level currently is.

Putting two of these modules together, switching at 200V and 140V, with all the other bits and pieces, we get this mess:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBFLlF.png)</sup>

For a slowly decreasing battery voltage, from 240V to 80V, current looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, the MOSFET action is much more emphatic, cutting out very sharply. The power dissipated in the two MOSFETs:

[image]

Neither MOSFET ever dissipates more than 250mW. There will probably be very short spikes, of course (because the MOSFETs cannot possibly switch instantly between states) too short to show on this time scale, but they'll be too short to dump any significant energy into the MOSFETs, to heat them.

That's it, that's all I have.

Comment: I kept scrolling and scrolling but the answer never ended! Anyway, the 6Ω gate resistance is indeed confusing but it's taken straight from the [datasheet](https://www.littelfuse.com/%7E/media/electronics/datasheets/discrete_mosfets/littelfuse_discrete_mosfets_n-channel_ultra_junction_ixtp8n65x2m_datasheet.pdf.pdf) listed as **Rgi** _Gate Input Resistance_ of 6Ω typ. No idea what they mean by that.

Comment: @pipe internal gate resistance is series connected to the gate. Gate is in first place similar to a kind of capacitor and internal gate resistance models the resistivity of the polysilicon which makes one the armatures. It's something to consider when fast driving the MOS for switching. From outside, electrically, you see (non linear) gate capacitance series to a resistance. This, again, it's not the whole story but a step further thou.

Comment: @carloc Ok, but OP is probably the one who cares.

Comment: You wrote you have no idea of what Rgi was. Anyway mine was just a side note, I don't think Rgi is relevant to anyone in this application.

Comment: "As you can see, there's a period of a couple of hours where the voltage across M1 is between 0 and the battery voltage." I think you must be off by several orders of magnitude here. The gate charge is 12 nC. The OP's resistor divider will supply mA. There is no way it works out to hours.

Comment: To be honest, I have no idea what I just read. The low voltage cutoffs are supplying 100% of the power to the gates of the mosfets, and if battery voltage is between 240v and 80v, with my divider offering a 10 to 1 ratio- these cutoffs will always be supplying between 24v and 8v to the gates. When the battery voltage falls below whatever low voltage I choose (the cutoffs are easily programmable) the cutoff will shut off and supply zero volts to the gate, turning them off. It would seem my design will work, so long as I don't expect to discharge the battery below 6v or so, which I don't.

Comment: I think I should have just NOT provided the schematic. It isn't entirely accurate and was meant to be a very rough sketch. Someone looking at it as a literal representation of my plan could be reasonably confused as to what I'm trying to accomplish. The 70,000 Ohm resistor in series is meant to represent the low voltage cutoff, which has a meter with about 70k ohm resistance. I can easily ensure that nothing kills me by putting a box around the mosfets. I'm just gonna do what I planned to do and I think I'll be just fine?

Comment: "Discharge the battery below 6v or so" was meant to say 60v or so. If the battery is at 60v the divider will be supplying 6v to the gate of the mosfet. In fact, I MAY decide to discharge below 60v, but if I do that I'll be manually driving the gates with an external voltage source.

Comment: @mkeith Sorry this wasn't clear; I agree the gate will charge pretty much instantly. I tried to show that the *battery* discharge from 240V to 80V is very slow (perhaps hours), and *that's* why the the MOSFET's gate potential will spend a lot of time around the knee, between 5.5V and 6V, between on and off states. I didn't mean to imply that this is due to gate charging time.

Comment: @DerekHershman My intent was really to show that if you use a resistor divider alone to provide gate potential, around the cut-off point the MOSFETs will spend a lot of time neither on or off, somewhere in between, during which time they will be dissipating a lot of power themselves. I tried to highlight this idea of the mOSFET **not** acting as an perfect on-off switch for a significant chunk of time. The second half (with all the comparators) was just a solution to that particular dilemma.

Comment: You have a graph showing Vd rising slowly from 0 volts up to Vbat over thousands of seconds. You have text saying that the voltage across M1 (Vds, I guess) will be between zero and Vbat for hours. Rather than reply to my comment, just fix your answer and then I will delete all my comments about this. The very first graph.

Comment: @DerekHershman In fact, I should have stopped talking after the first pair of graphs. It just felt wrong at the time to leave it there, without showing you at least one way of producing a proper on/off digital signal that would protect the MOSFETs.

Comment: The first two graphs are EXTREMELY misleading. If you meant it to show voltage response you shouldn't have made the X-axis be time. And you should not have referred to hours of time when the channel is not fully enhanced. Afterall the OP has not given us any indication of battery capacity or load current so we have no idea how long the time will be.

Comment: @mkeith I get your point, it's a good one. I assure you I did consider using a DC sweep to obtain a voltage vs. voltage graph. The reason I decided to go with time on X is because CircuitLab's DC sweep doesn't allow a high-to-low sweep, and I really wanted to stay in context of the battery voltage dropping over time. That's why I also included Vbat on the same graph, to keep "context". I do get your point though, and it may have been the wrong decision.

Comment: If the gate is getting between 8 and 24 volts it should be behaving as fully on, yes? I understand that at 8 volts it may be *marginally* less on than at 10v (the nominal gate drive) but this difference should be miniscule, correct? So as long as I can guarantee 8v or more to the gate of the mosfet, it is on and drain will flow to source, and dissipation will just be a function of drain to source current and the resistance of the mosfet, which is very low. I'm not relying on battery voltage to turn the mosfets off, the cutoffs will cut that 8-24v supply to the mosfet gate for switching off.

Comment: To be clear- I *am* relying on battery voltage to cut voltage to the gates, but indirectly. Battery voltage will dictate whether my cutoffs are, well, cutting off or not. If I want the first mosfet to turn off when the battery is at 180v, I'll program the voltage divider-fed cutoff to stop sending power to the mosfet gate when it reads 18v. At this point the mosfet gate will get 0v and be turned off entirely.  Right?

Comment: @DerekHershman Yes, correct. Your understanding of the MOSFET's role here is correct. If you provide 10V or 18V or 20V at the gate, it's on, all the way. If you put 0V at the gate, or 1V or any voltage under some limit defined by the MOSFET, it's off, fully off.

Comment: Okay, I think we can chalk up all the additional confusion to me asking the question in a dumb way. While I have you here- one last question. The gate voltage maximum is 30v. I've seen a lot of "do not exceed or even come close to" this number sort of warnings. So, is putting 24v to a gate with a 30v max somehow bad? Short of a bunch of different failures from a bunch of different components I can guarantee that the gate will never see any *more* than 24v (and I've got a circuit breaker as a master switch which I can throw in case of such catastrophe to stop all discharge).

Comment: Yeah, that's fine! If the datasheet says 30V max, then 24V is fine. Even 30V will be fine, the manufacturer is sure to be conservative, and leave some margin for error. I wouldn't feel comfortable going to the extreme in a design, but if I built a circuit with a MOSFET rated for \$V_{GSMAX}=30V\$, and it blew up when I applied 30V, that's a manufacturing defect, or a lie.

Comment: Right on, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Will it work? It looks like it will probably work. I would put a Zener diode from gate to source anyway (similar to what I did in my schematic below). In your schematic, R3 seems to serve little purpose but it will do no harm.

Actually I think the easiest thing will be a pullup resistor and a Zener diode. I would size the pullup for 1 mA when the battery is at max voltage. You don't need hardly any current to keep a mosfet gate on.

Putting in a resistor divider that requires heat sinking seems to me to be totally unnecessary. If you are willing to use a heatsink, put it on the FET to make sure it doesn't get hot while turning on.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fN7kvV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

R1 will still dissipate a few hundred mW. I guess I would use a 1W resistor. You could improve this a LOT by using a high input voltage LDO instead of a Zener. But you seem to be favoring simplicity over all else.

Comment: So- I agree that using a divider that requires a heatsink seems unnecessary.  However, I'm building a battery discharge module, essentially. So the whole goal is to dissipate a ton of watts of battery power. the 10:1 divider in question has a ton of conveniences further down the line for my specific application, as this resistance value is essentially what I want for my "battery voltage is low, lets discharge very slowly" phase of the operation.

Comment: Well, if it were me, I would move the battery voltage is low lets discharge very slowly resistor off-board from the MOSFET. But clearly there is more to your plan than you have included in your question. I sense that perhaps your plan could be revised if you shared all that you are trying to accomplish. But the answer to your basic question is yes, it will turn on the MOSFET and hold it on until some poorly controlled cutoff occurs. Probably you should add a low-voltage cutoff of some sort to avoid burning out the MOSFET when the battery voltage gets too low (somewhere below 80 V).

Comment: Yeah, just spelled it out a bit more in an edit to the question. Each and every mosfet will get it's own low voltage cut off. Basically the mosfet just needs to act as the switch instead of the low voltage cut offs because the cut offs are rated for 0-60v, and therefore can't be the switch.